# How to find what intercepts my form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My `<form>` submit is not doing anything, I think it's because the action is intercepted by some JQuery code (what else can it be?). In my reasonably complex web application, I can't even find which line of code is intercepting the action -- yes I wrote every line of them, but still I have no idea.

The question is: in general, is there an effective way to trace which piece of JavaScript code is intercepting a designated action?

Comment: It turns out that nothing is intercepting my form submit action. To save screen space, I'm hiding, and showing, all comment submit buttons as -- `$('.comment_submit_button').hide();
$('.comment_textarea').focus(function() {
   $(this).closest('form').find('.comment_submit_button').show();
});
$('.comment_submit_button').blur(function() {
   $(this).closest('form').find('.comment_submit_button').hide();
});
` When I click on a submit button, its comment textarea `blur` faithfully hides the submit button and does not submit my form. Getting rid of the above JS works, but is there a real answer?

Answer (score 9):

```
console.log($('form').data('events'));
```

will give you a list of attached events to the given DOM element.

and you could even get the source code of it:

```
$.each($('form').data('events'), function () {
    $.each(this, function () {
        console.log(this['handler'].toString());
    });
});
```

Comment: This might not be exhaustive, even for jQuery code. E.g. you can hijack a click on the submit button: http://jsfiddle.net/hbDah/

Comment: @millimoose, in this case simply adapt the selector and in addition to forms, take `:submit` as well.

Comment: +1 Thank you. It's precisely because nothing is logged in the console that led me to focus on the `blur` function.

Answer (score 2):

a quick and easy way would be using Google Chrome's developer tools.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Choose your element.
- Click on the event to see the handler that might be "intercepting" your `submit`

[image]